# Weird text (CSS) on wordpress checkout page

Tags: css, wordpress

can someone please help me about this Wordpress CSS problem. On the checkout page the payment methods float right and for some reason the method description text is 'vertical', instead of having sentences in the full row, only 2 or 3 letters appear in each row (image included).

When I change the window size (and on mobile) everything looks okay.

Can anyone help me with some css code which would fix this? I don't know how to edit stuff that isn't in styles.css.

The problem
[image]

when i resize the window / mobile screen
[image]

The link:
https://zelenakuca.com/checkout/

Thank you!

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried, and share some code we can look at and use to help you.

Comment: I haven't tried anything since I don't know how to change wordpress css which isn't in styles.css. I tried playing with elements in google chrome's inspect element but haven't found anything. One time i 'changed' (in inspect element) some code which contained 37.8% (i changed the percentage, or deleted it) and that seemed to work, but I couldn't find it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Paste media code with style before line code
```

`</style><noscript><style type="text/css"> .wpb_animate_when_almost_visible { opacity: 1; }</style></noscript></head>` in index page or file.

```
@media (min-width: 1025px)
    {
    #order_review {
        width: 100%;
    }
    }
```

Comment: sorry but I cannot find that ''</style><noscript>'' in index.php, where is that code?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, I put this code in header.php and it worked, thank you very much!!!!!

Comment: I am glade that it worked, If this answer is worked, please marked it as answer accepted, so others can get benefit from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try these CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1025px){

 #order_review {
 float: none;
 width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i added this code to styles.css in wordpress editor but nothing happened // changed

Comment: @media (min-width: 1025px){

 #order_review {
 float: none !important;
 width: 100% !important;
    }
} // try this